# Automatically mask np.ma array when item set equal to fill_value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I'm a bit surprised by the behavior of numpy.ma masked arrays and its `fill_value`. When I for example create an array as:

```
a = np.ma.array(np.zeros(4), mask=True, fill_value=-9999)
```

And change one of its values (e.g. `a[2] = 1`), the mask is automatically set to False:

```
masked_array(data = [-- -- 1.0 --],
             mask = [ True  True False  True],
       fill_value = -9999.0)
```

But the other way around, if I set `a[2]` equal to the `fill_value` of this masked array, the item isn't automatically masked:

```
masked_array(data = [-- -- -9999.0 --],
             mask = [ True  True False  True],
       fill_value = -9999.0)
```

Is there an automatic way to make `np.ma` automatically set the mask of an element to `True` when it's value is set equal to the `fill_value`?

Comment: Normally a value is masked because the corresponding element of the mask is True.  It doesn't work the other way - the mask is not set because the value equals the fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review the masking documentation.  Masking affects how values are displayed and used in calculations; but it is not directly affected by the values.  That is, an value is not masked just because if equals the fill.

But looking at masking methods I see one that is described as:

> masked_object(x, value[, copy, shrink])   Mask the array x where the data are exactly equal to value.

Let's experiment with it?

```
In [185]: a = np.ma.array(np.zeros(4,int), mask=True, fill_value=-9999)
In [186]: a[2]=3
In [187]: a
Out[187]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 3 --],
             mask = [ True  True False  True],
       fill_value = -9999)
In [188]: a[2]=a.fill_value
In [189]: a
Out[189]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- -9999 --],
             mask = [ True  True False  True],
       fill_value = -9999)
In [190]: np.ma.masked_object(a,a.fill_value)
Out[190]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- -- --],
             mask = [ True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = -9999)
```

So it returned a copy with that `a[2]` element masked - because it equals the fill_value.  I switched to 'int' here to avoid the floating point equality issues.  There's another method that handles floating point equality.

> masked_values(x, value[, rtol, atol, copy, ...])  Mask using floating point equality.

If `a[2]=np.inf` (for the float `a`), then `np.ma.masked_invalid` could be used.

Later in the masked documentation I find:

> The recommended way to mark one or several specific entries of a masked array as invalid is to assign the special value masked to them:

```
a[2]=np.ma.masked
```

What you saw with `a[2]=2` is explained by

> To unmask one or several specific entries, we can just assign one or several new valid values to them:

Masked arrays are a way of removing invalid values from calculations like `mean`.  The `fill_value` is not an invalid value; the fill is used to replace the masked values in other operations.  Invalid values may 'floats' like `np.nan` and `np.inf`, or anything else that fits you problem (e.g. negatives).